# How do I unit test a method that contains a CompletableFuture?

Tags: java, unit-testing

I tried looking this up, but couldn't quite understand the examples I found. I have a class with a Spring `AfterPropertiesSet()` method that calls 2 other methods to spin off asynch calls. I'm at a loss how as to to unit test them. The method `startProcessingThread()` looks like this:

```
void startProcessingThread(executor) {
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        Path filePath = null;       
        do {
            filePath = retrieveFromFileQueue();
            submitFileForProcessing(filePath);            
        } while (keepRunning);
    }, executor)
    .handle((theVoid, exception) -> {           
        if (exception != null) {
            LOG.error("Error submitting file for processing: " + exception);            
        }
        return null;
    });
}
```

I don't want to rewrite the `CompletableFuture` in the test method (do I?). So I figured I need to call `startProcessingThread()`, using Mocks (from Mockito) inside the methods that need them (`retrieveFromFileQueue()` and `submitFileForProcessing()`). But what about the `CompletableFuture` itself? Should I mock that? I'm sorry, but I'm really confused...

Comment: This code does not wait for the `CompletableFutur` to finish nor it uses it's result. Why did you choose it in favour to an ordinary `Runnable`?

Comment: You should create the lambda in a different method (or as an class of its own). Then you can mock it and check, that this method runs it (have your test wait a few ms after calling the method), also you can verify the lambdas behavior itself directly.

Comment: Timothy, this code is not my design. I'm not really sure why a CompletableFuture was used. Does it not have any advantages over a Runnable, the way it's currently used??

Comment: Also, we decided we didn't want to put a sleep in a unit test method. So for now we're just going to test it during integration.

Comment: *"we decided we didn't want to put a sleep in a unit test method."* wtith the change I suggestet the resulting method would be *to simple to fail" so that is would be no risk not to UnitTest is, but you could still thest the logic of the rinnable/CompletableFuture.

Comment: *"this code is not my design."* neither mine... *"[...] Does it not have any advantages over a Runnable, the way it's currently used??"* I only know this little snipped you showed, so I cannot aswer this. Ask the one who wrote it.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid non deterministic logic in your test and so I would advise to avoid sleep. Instead you can use Mockito's "when" instead of "verify" and wait until the action was performed:

```
final xyz[] result = new[]{null};
final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
when(submitFileForProcessing(...).thenAnswer((Answer<Lwm2mCommand>) invocationOnMock ->
{
    result[0] = invocationOnMock.getArgument(index); // if you need to check the values passed to your method call

    latch.countDown();
}

// Call your method
        assertTrue(latch.await(60L, TimeUnit.SECONDS));
// If needed check the parameters passed to the mocked method
```

One more tip: I wouldn't mock the actual class under test - instead I would mock one of the dependencies used.